# Рефакторинг пространств имен

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespace

Допустим, я создаю папочку в Project и там создаю файлы-кода.

Создаваемые файлы кода имеют в Namespace название этой папки и  это круто.

Однако когда я меняю название этой папки, то Namespace в уже созданных файлах кода не меняется и приходится ручками по ним идти и менять...

Есть в вижуалке какое-то штатное решение этой проблемы или может быть какой-то бесплатный плагин?

Comment: В студии не помню, но в решарпере точно есть.

Comment: [Вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/sync-namespace-and-folder-name?view=vs-2019) что нашел.

Comment: [NamespaceFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p2410.NamespaceFixer)

Comment: @aepot оформи ответом. Эта штука работает и меняет спейсы во всем проекте.

Comment: Это как бы не ответ, а просто ссылка. Можете сами расписать это ответом и сами его принять, если считаете нужным, я не против.